# Can you use a float array in a WebGL Shader?

Tags: webgl

I'm trying to use a WebGL shader to visualize some audio data. I have an array of number which represent a normalized .wav file:

```js
"demo": {"duration": 0.021111111111111112, "samplerate": 44100, "subsample": 100, "data": 
[-0.018585205078125, -0.05145263671875, 0.0645751953125, -0.059326171875, 0.006072998046875, 
-0.0294189453125, 0.04620361328125, 0.0694580078125, -0.0849609375, -0.053253173828125, 
-0.133697509765625, 0.002166748046875, 0.110931396484375, 0.052337646484375, 0.1214599609375, 
-0.19488525390625, 0.00970458984375, 0.0145263671875, -0.01446533203125, 0.12530517578125, 
-0.115997314453125, 0.010589599609375, -0.127838134765625, 0.0775146484375, -0.0048828125, 
0.001007080078125, -0.164337158203125, -0.146270751953125, 0.077545166015625, -0.012725830078125, 
0.087158203125, -0.130462646484375, 0.088287353515625, -0.02996826171875, 0.156280517578125, 
0.0230712890625, 0.199920654296875, -0.062164306640625, -0.166107177734375, 0.04888916015625, 
-0.00384521484375, 0.1611328125, -0.153961181640625, -0.164947509765625, 0.03314208984375, 
0.098052978515625, 0.042083740234375, 0.1318359375, -0.2388916015625, 0.100006103515625, 
0.04754638671875, 0.009674072265625, 0.1630859375, -0.161834716796875, 0.005584716796875, 
-0.126953125, 0.04388427734375, 0.048095703125, 0.13763427734375, -0.148406982421875, 
-0.250274658203125, 0.04815673828125, 0.087371826171875, 0.0931396484375, -0.02789306640625, 
-0.282073974609375, 0.134063720703125, 0.14483642578125, -0.0025634765625, 0.206756591796875, 
-0.350555419921875, 0.19439697265625, -0.004638671875, 0.03741455078125, 0.203338623046875, 
-0.222137451171875, 0.04315185546875, -0.19219970703125, 0.10284423828125, 0.069976806640625, 
0.062530517578125, -0.0782470703125, -0.22076416015625, 0.13287353515625, 0.031341552734375, 
0.08673095703125]}
```

I've been looking at [this example](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-qna-how-to-get-audio-data-into-a-shader.html) of using audio data in a shader via a `Uint8Array(numPoints)`, and wondering:

- Is my normalized waveform data able to be converted to a `Uint8Array`?
- Are `Uint8Array`s the only kind of array you can pass into into a shader?
- My actual waveforms contain a lot of data and are about ~1MB. I'm wondering if this is an unreasonable amount of data to try and pass into the shader via a texture, and if there might be a way for me to "subsample" the data so that fewer points are needed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could certainly convert your normalized data to unsigned bytes you may just use floating point textures via the [`OES_texture_float`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_texture_float) extension (not needed with WebGL2 contexts). 1MB of data is not that much considering that a single RGBA FullHD framebuffer already is ~8.3MB and the [minimum supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGL_API/WebGL_best_practices) max texture size is 4096(=67.1MB). Whether you can sparsely sample the data depends on your requirements / usecase.

Comment: Great answer. Wondering, can we effectively achieve sparse sampling via the texture [lod extension](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EXT_shader_texture_lod)? Does specifying the lod effectively specify how many samples of the texture we want to use?

Comment: Yes however iirc you'd need to generate the mipmaps manually as `generateMipmap` it's not supported for floating point textures, you may utilize linear filtering(through the [OES_texture_float_linear](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/OES_texture_float_linear) extension) to implicitly average datapoints depending on your sampling pattern.